# How does one Graph $y= \sin (x/8)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I studied trigonometric functions this summer, however, I am lost as to how to apply what I learned to this problem.

The question asks me to plot this function.

1) It is a sine function so the range is $[-1,1]$, right?

2) It is a sine function so the domain is $(0, 2\pi)$?

Not to sure how to approach this problem when I see it. Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: 1/8 is the coefficient of x.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if we've got a function $f(x)$, the graph of $f(ax)$ (where $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ ) is the graph of $f(x)$ stretched parallel to the $x-$axis by a factor of $1/a.$

Therefore, $\sin\left(\frac{1}{8}x \right)$ is just the graph of $\sin(x)$, just stretched $\frac{1}{1/8}=8$ times wider.

---

Note that the domain of $\sin$  is $\mathbb{R}$. I can take the sine of any real number.

Regarding the range of $\sin\left(\frac{1}{8}x \right)$, you tell me: does stretching the graph horizontally affect the set of values produced by $\sin$? What can you conclude about the range, from this?

Answer (score 1):

The first observation you should make is that if you divide all the values in the reals by eight, you will still get the reals back. Thus $y(\frac{1}{8}x)$ will still produce a range of values between $-1$ and $1$.

Now, the domain is the values of x you are limiting the function to. If you only want to have one period of the sign function, $(0,2\pi)$ is not going to do it any more.

Think about it this way, for each value of y, you are only getting an eighth of the x you would normally receive. What does this indicate? You have to go 8 times as far down the x-axis to plot the same function.

Understand?

As a further thought. What would happen if you had $\sin(x) + b$? Think about what happens to the y values in terms of x with this new expression. You might try subbing in a value of x to see.

Now what about $a\sin(x)$?